# One of Log.d methods doesn't execute and doesn't throw an exception at the same time

Tags: java, android, debugging, redis, logcat

I have a few lines of Android Java code which are supposed to create a JReJSON (*A Java Client Library for RedisJSON*) object and print some data from my DB to Logcat:

```
            GenericObjectPoolConfig config = new GenericObjectPoolConfig();
            config.setJmxEnabled(false);
            config.setMaxTotal(128);
            JedisPool pool = new JedisPool(config,"192.168.0.120", 6381);
            JReJSON client = new JReJSON(pool);
            client.set("foo", "bar");
            Log.d("myTag", (String)client.get("foo"));
            LinkedTreeMap RusPro = client.get("RusPro");
            String str = RusPro.toString();
            Log.d("myTag", str + "xxx");
            Log.d("MyTag", (String)client.get("ANV"));
```

`Log.d("myTag", (String)client.get("foo"));` and `Log.d("MyTag", (String)client.get("ANV"));` work well: the strings stored in this keys are showed in Logcat. But `Log.d("myTag", str + "xxx");` doesn't do anything: there is no message from this line of code in Logcat. So, my program just skips this piece of code not executing it. If I simply write `Log.d("myTag", "xxx");`, it will work. But as soon as I add `str`  in the method, it won't.

So, this is the Logcat:

```
2020-04-30 21:57:36.545 9740-9928/io.SamsungProject D/myTag: bar //"foo" value
2020-04-30 21:57:36.552 9740-9928/io.SamsungProject D/MyTag: hello! //"ANV" value
```

What is the problem? Why the program "pass by" the line? There is not any exceptions as well.

Comment: Did you try to use get with class? https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.redislabs/jrejson/latest/index.html
`LinkedTreeMap RusPro = client.get("RusPro", LinkedTreeMap.class, ".");`

Comment: @GuyKorland it says `cannot resolve method 'get(java.lang.String, java.lang.Class<com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap>, java.langString`

Comment: @GuyKorland https://pastebin.com/ACTAQZBn - this is the value for "RusPro". Maybe there are some other ways to convert it to string? Anyway, the fact that Log.d with the value I tried to get doesn't print anything is really weird

Comment: As for the cannot resolve, issue, try to upgrade the jrejson client

Comment: @GuyKorland I think it is up to date. I installed it about 1-2 weeks ago by downloading jrejson-1.2.0.jar from Maven Repository

Comment: I suggest you open an issue on https://github.com/RedisJSON/JRedisJSON/issues